# Python Range Function with Print Fuction

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still learning python 3 and I wrote this code but i can't figure out the last output being 9

```
    for y in range(10):
         print(y)
    print(y)
```

output
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
9

I can't figure out why it gives 9 at the end.

Comment: because `range` upper value is exclusive - `range(10)` goes from 0 to 9. Not 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for y in range(10):   #1
   print (y)          #2
print (y)             #3
```

The `for loop` ends in line 2. Until line 2, the loop would have printed `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. After the loop, at line 3, value of `y`is 9. So, it prints 9.